# How to backup 'Favorite tracks' playlist

Tags: samsung, backup, factory-reset

Have a Samsung Galaxy 4S (SPH-L720) running Android 5.0.1.  Ever since upgrading Android, phone hangs or reboots randomly at least once or twice a day.  I would like to try restoring to factory defaults to see if it fixes, but don't want to lose the 'Favorite tracks' playlist that the music app creates when you 'star' a track.  This doesn't seem to be located with other playlists.  Any ideas where it is stored, or how I can back it up?

Comment: Have you tried *adb [tag:backup]*?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Kies. If that's not an option you can download [Playlist Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.ssi.playlistbackup&hl=en) and use it to back-up your playlist. This application allows you to export your audio playlists (both System, Poweramp and Google Play Music playlists) to sdcard or Dropbox. You can keep as many backups as you want for each playlist, but as  metadata.

Comment: I do have Playlist Backup, and love it.  But it does not back up the special 'Favorite Tracks' playlist.  This playlist is not stored in the same place as the others.  If I knew where it was stored, I could back it up myself.